# Photoshop CC 2015: "Place Linked" -> Target specific Artboard instead whole PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, artboard

I use the "Place Linked" function a lot to keep my files organised. I recently switched to Artboards, so now I have multiple Artboards in a PSD.

Is there a way to use the "Place Linked" function and target a specific Artboard in a PSD?

Here's a really simple example:

- Two PSD's
- "Header.PSD" -> a File with three Artboards: "Large", "Medium", "Small"
- "Home.PSD" -> a file with three Artboards: "Large", "Medium", "Small"

I want to link the "Medium" Artboard from "Header.PSD" into my "Home.PSD" file. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to target a specific artboard. Instead, I can only Link the entire "Header.PSD".

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a workaround to this? How do you keep your files organised when working with Artboards?

Comment: I have last version of Photoshop CC 2015.5.1 and there is still no way how to *place* only specific Artboard.
It should work like with pages of PDF file when you placing it. Like *Import options* there should be *Placing options*... OMG I don't understand how this is possible - sooo big company, so famous software and still stupid in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality isn't possible with the current software limitations.

Your best bet is to export artboards to file as detailed in this post:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76064/43400

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the optimum use would be to create `Header.psd` as a *separate* file - no artboard, standard single .psd file. Then link `header.psd` to any other .psd in need of it.

```
Header.psd ---> Home.psd
Header.psd ---> Page2.psd
Header.psd ---> Page3.psd
```

Often I find separate *assets* then master files linking to those assets works best rather than suffering through the frustrations of pulling assets from one file for another file.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off visibility on the artboards your don't need, save and place linked. Just the visible artboard will be placed.