# Only exporting one artboard in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, artboard, mac

I started using artboards in Photoshop, they are great for making banner sets. However, I've just had to change something in only 1 of my banners.

If I use 'File > Export as...' it only gives me the 'Export All' option. How do I exclude artboards or just pick one for export?

The goal is to save one of my artboards to a JPG banner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of "Export As...", select "File > Export > Artboards to Files":

[image]

This will give you the option to export the selected Artboard only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I skipped trying this because 'artboard*s*' suggested to me this was also meant for more than one artboard :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also right-click on the artboard name in the Layers panel and choose "Quick export as PNG" (or "Export As..." and choose the appropriate format and quality settings).

Answer (score 0):

If a Photoshop file has artboards File > Export > Export As will only allow you to export all artboards

You also have the option to select whatever artboards you want, right click > export as and that will bring the same window as in your case but only for the selected artboards.

[source](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html)