# How do I "Render Video" of a single artboard in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Photoshop (PSD) file containing several artboards as well as a timeline animation. I would like to export the animation contained in one of those artboards as a PNG sequence. Ordinarily in a Photoshop file without artboards, I would just use the "File->Export->Render Video" command to render out the PNG sequence. But if I do that in my file with multiple artboards, it renders out *all* of the artboards, not just the artboard I have selected.

How can I get Photoshop to render a PNG sequence of only a single artboard? (I've already tried making the other artboards invisible, but Photoshop still renders out blank space where those artboards would be.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with rendering video from artboards, but since artboards are kind of a new thing, I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't possible...... Unless you remove all the other artboards and then render video. You may want to post this in the Photoshop feedback website.

Comment: This [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/only-exporting-one-artboard-in-photoshop) is about exporting one artboard

Answer (score 0):

just figured this out by accident.

Go to FILE > EXPORT > ARTBOARDS TO FILES

When you export your animated artboard then timeline will be intact in the new file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I know I'm late, but what I did was:

turn off all the artboards you're not exporting --> save for web/legacy --> gif

EDIT: i just realized this doesn't answer you're question, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to export gifs individually using artboards, so for whoever stumbles across this, I hope it help bc there are no answers for this problem anywhere.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110758)

Answer (score 0):

Late as well. Save your artboards as smart objects. Open the smart object and render the video from there.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I found some foolish way to export without overlapping each artboards.
Just stack whole artboards on X0 Y0 position. after that, just turn the boards on one by one when you're exporting. I know it is pathetic method but, it is the fastest way to render the artboards I found. (But Im not sure it work when you export artboards of different size, sry.)